# Taking limits on integration limits.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, approximation

For some function $f$ and $g$ lets say that I have an integral which looks like, $\int ^{f(\epsilon)}_0 g(t,\epsilon) dt$. So if I want to compute this to zeroth order in $\epsilon$ can I just truncate the Taylor series of $f$ and $g$ to the zeroth order in $\epsilon$ and get the answer?

(..so as a special case if the Taylor series of $f$ has no term in the zeroth order of $\epsilon$ then shouldn't the answer be $0$ no matter what is $g$?..)

---

I am asking this because $g$ is so complicated that the full integral can't be done. So I don't have the luxury of doing the full integral and then taking the $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ limit.

Comment: I think this is correct. If you treat the integral as a function $h(\epsilon)$, then to get the zeroth order approximation at $\epsilon = 0$, you would just set $\epsilon = 0$, which would truncate $f$ and $g$ at the zeroth order. But to get the higher order terms, you would have to use the fundamental theorem of calculus, and not just truncate.

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh Thanks! And would anything in the prescription change if the lower limit were not $0$ but some another function say $f_2(\epsilon)$?

Comment: No. It would be the same. To see this even more immediately, you could treat the new integral as the difference of two integrals, both with $0$ on the bottom and $f_{1}, f_{2}$ respectively on the top.